# Drop-down for populating a list of cities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a drop-down to populate a list of cities. Everything works fine, but I would like to know better ways of doing this. Also, please let me know if it is possible to create the same drop down using `<Select>` instead of HTML helpers.

```
//ViewModel

public class LocationDTO
{
    public IEnumerable<CityDTO> Cities { get; set; }
    public LocationDTO()
    {
        this.Cities = new CityDTO[] { };
    }
}

public class CityDTO
{
    public string CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
}
```

I've used entity framework database first approach to get the data back from database. Please address improvements that need to be done.

```
//Controller

Models.LocationDTO Loc = new Models.LocationDTO();
EF.LocationEntities locCtx = new EF.LocationEntities();

public Action Result Index() {
    using(locCtx) { 
        var locResults    = (from q in locCtx.usp_GetAllCities()
                       Select new Models.CityDTO {
                       CityId = q.Id, 
                       CityName = q.Name  }); 
        loc.Cities = locResults.ToList();
    }

    List<Models.CityDTO> citiesList = new List<Models.CityDTO>();
    Models.CityDTO city = new Models.CityDTO() { CityId = "-1", CityName = "Select City" };
    citiesList.Add(city);
    citiesList.AddRange(Loc.Cities.ToList());

    ViewBag.CitiesDropDown = citiesList;
    return view(loc);
}
```

I'd also like to know how the lamdba expression works in this scenario:

```
//View

@{
    List<TestApp.Models.CityDTO> citiesList = ViewBag.CitiesDropDown;
    var cityItems = new SelectList(citiesList, "CityId", "CityName");
}
<div>
    Cities: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Cities.SingleOrDefault().CityID, @cityItems)
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**View Model**

Looks fine to me, although I'd recommend that if all your DTO classes are to be appended with 'DTO' you instead put them inside a namespace named 'DTO' and leave the 'DTO' characters off the class names entirely.

**Controller**

Use `var` when the Right Hand Side (RHS) is obvious.

Also, I don't like the indentation in your LINQ statement. It makes it difficult to discern between LINQ and constructor.

There is no point in calling `ToList` so much. AddRange is going to enumerate the whole collection anyway, so you don't actually need any `ToList` calls at all.

```
var Loc = new Models.LocationDTO();
var locCtx = new EF.LocationEntities();

public Action Result Index() {
    using(locCtx) { 
        var locResults = (from q in locCtx.usp_GetAllCities()
                             Select new Models.CityDTO 
                             {
                                 CityId = q.Id, 
                                 CityName = q.Name
                             }); 
        loc.Cities = locResults;
    }

    var citiesList = new List<Models.CityDTO>();
    var city = new Models.CityDTO()
    {
        CityId = "-1", 
        CityName = "Select City" 
    };
    citiesList.Add(city);
    citiesList.AddRange(Loc.Cities);

    ViewBag.CitiesDropDown = citiesList;
    return view(loc);
}
```

**View**

You make a call to `Cities.SingleOrDefault()`. `SingleOrDefault()` can return a null value if your `City` class' default operator returns null (which is the *err* default behaviour). If this happens, accessing `CityId` will fail.

```
//View

@{
    List<TestApp.Models.CityDTO> citiesList = ViewBag.CitiesDropDown;
    var cityItems = new SelectList(citiesList, "CityId", "CityName");
}
<div>
    Cities: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Cities.SingleOrDefault().CityID, @cityItems)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- For the DTOs, namespace them and keep them at that level. It's hard to add more here without more context around what you are doing.

View

- In your view, you should not be doing the code inside of your @. This should all take place at the controller level or lower. Also, you should have a strongly typed ViewModel that contains exactly what the view needs.

Controller

- Too much logic here. That query should be contained inside of a service/repository and you should simply call _cityService.GetAllCities() in the controller.
- After that's done, you can create a class to map from the cities to whatever you need to have in your viewmodel.
- Remove the ViewBag use, create a strongly typed ViewModel that you pass to your view.